# Sluggish typing with wireless keyboard

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, wireless-keyboards

How do you fix typing on Ubuntu getting progressively slower over time?

I recently upgraded a mini PC to Ubuntu 22, and now typing on it with a wireless keyboard is very sluggish. If I type too fast, it doesn't register keypresses, forcing me to type frustratingly slowly.

I'm pretty sure it's not the keyboard, as it has a fresh battery. Plus, whenever I reboot the machine, it can again quickly register fast keypresses. It's like there's some sort of problem that builds up over time causing the machine to slow down. However, all I use the machine for is web browsing and for exposing a printer to my network.

Comment: If a reboot fixes the problem, probably not a mechanical (loose antenna) or thermal.  What does the memory look like when fast/slow?  When available system buffers fill up/get used, things can slow down -- are other things slow like dragging windows around? Any mounted things that are critical, but may be too small (like /tmp)?